# Show that $\| x \| = \sup \{ |x^*(x)|: x^* \in X^*, \| x^* \| \leq 1 \}$

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose $X$ is a normed space. Show that for every $x \in X$, 
$$\| x \| = \sup \{ |x^*(x)|: x^* \in X^*, \|  x^* \| \leq 1 \}$$

I obtain the fact above from the book 'Topics in Banach Space Theory', page $338$, under Cornerstone Theorems of Functional Analysis.

It is stated as a corollary of the Hahn-Banach Theorem. But I am wondering how one proves it using the Hahn-Banach theorem. Can anyone enlighten me?

I need to know how to show this because I need this to show that $\| e_x \| = \| x \|$ where $e_x : X^* \rightarrow \mathbb{F}$ is an evaluation map.

Comment: [A related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1151783/trouble-applying-hahn-banach-theorem)

Comment: @DanielFischer: According to your link, it seems that the bounded linear functional $x^*$ in the set above is not applicable for ALL functionals, am I right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. For different $x$, the supremum is attained at different functionals $x^{\ast}$ (generally). But the point is that for each $x$, there is at least one $x^{\ast}$ where the supremum is attained.

Answer (score 1):

First observe $\sup \{ |x^*(x)|: x^* \in X^*, \|  x^* \| \leq 1 \}\leq\|x\|$, which is easy to see. We'd like to show that the supremum is attained. To that end, we'd like to construct a functional $x^*$ such that $\|x^*\| = 1$ and $x^*(x) = \|x\|$.

Define $W = \{t x \mid t \in \mathbb{K}\}$, i.e. the one dimensional subspace of $X$ spanned by $x$. On $W$, define $g(t x) = t \|x\|$. Clearly $g$ is linear, $\|g\|=1$ and $g(x) = \|x\|$. So, use Hahn-Banach to extend it to $x^*$, defined on all of $X$. This satisfies the required properties.